# How to swap single player and arcade mode ships?

Tags: tyrian

The [Wikipedia on Tyrian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyrian_(video_game)) says:

> It is possible to switch between the Single Player and (1 person) Arcade modes using a secret routine (not cheat codes). Since it is possible to find exotic weapons early in Arcade Mode (by contrast in Single Player, such weapons can only be bought at the end), using this switch will allow such weapons to be brought over to single player. Likewise, generator and shield upgrades from single player will result in a better ship for Arcade Mode.

What is this secret routine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Source: http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/564490-tyrian/faqs/1638*

### To bring a ship from arcade mode into single player:

- Start a game in arcade mode.
- Play until you get the weapons you want, and then finish that level.
- Then start the next level and immediately hit ESC.  Then quit the level.
- Quit the arcade-mode game and select Load Game from the main menu
- Select "Last Level" option (alternatively, start a Full Game and use the load command from the options menu).

#### A warning:

Anything you bring from arcade mode into the full game and then sell is gone for good

### To bring a ship from single player into arcade mode:

- Select Start New Game.
- Select 1 Player Arcade.
- When the episode selection screen comes up, don't select an episode.  Press Escape to return to the main menu.
- Load a game.

Answer (score -1):

here is fine link that answers your question it is you need to read the 17. ! :)
http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/564490-tyrian/faqs/1638

Comment: In the future please summarize the content you're linking in case the site goes defunct, as in Steve V.'s answer.